# php function ( add html to theme ) not work

Tags: php, html, function

this is my code ( in file comment.php ) :

```
<?php $args = array(
    'comment_field' =>
        '<div class="comment-form-comment">
            <div class="comment-form-emoji-icon">
                <img src="'.get_bloginfo('template_url').'/Image/emoji.png" onclick="invertShowEmojiList()">
                <div class="comment-form-emoji-list" id="ID_EmojiList">'.
                    showAllEmoje() .
                '</div>
            </div>
            <textarea id="comment" name="comment" cols="45" rows="4" required placeholder="دیدگاه شما..." ></textarea>
        </div>',
);

comment_form( $args ); ?>
```

and i define function "showAllEmoje" ( in file function.php)

```
function showAllEmoje() {
    $dirname = get_bloginfo('template_url').'/Image/emoji/';
    $images = glob($dirname."*.gif");
    foreach($images as $image) {
        echo '<img src="'.$image.'" onclick="add_emojiCode_to_coment_textAria(\'[:'.$image.':]\');" >';
    }
};
```

but this function ( showAllEmoje() ) not work;

Comment: `showAllEmoje` needs to *return* the text for it to work, since you're concatenating it.

Comment: This is interesting, and something I've never thought of. However, reading @Jeto's comment got me curious: https://3v4l.org/naY1V

Comment: i test return  - but it not word

Comment: "Not work" is a really broad description of your problem.....

Answer (score 0):

`Echo` inside your method, will not work here, because you are concatenating, you can store your result in an array and then use `return` LIKE:

```
function showAllEmoje() {
    $dirname = get_bloginfo('template_url').'/Image/emoji/';
    $images = glob($dirname."*.gif");
    $imagesArr = array(); // initialize an array
    foreach($images as $image) {
        // store in an array
        $imagesArr[] = '<img src="'.$image.'" onclick="add_emojiCode_to_coment_textAria(\'[:'.$image.':]\');" >';
    }
    return $imagesArr;
};
```

Then, call your method and store it in a variable.

```
$functionResult = showAllEmoje(); // method calling
```

Then, you can use concatenation LIKE:

```
$yourHTML = '<div class="comment-form-comment">
            <div class="comment-form-emoji-icon">
                <img src="'.get_bloginfo('template_url').'/Image/emoji.png" onclick="invertShowEmojiList()">
                <div class="comment-form-emoji-list" id="ID_EmojiList">';

$yourHTML .= implode("<br/>",$functionResult); // using implode() to print

$yourHTML .= '</div>
            </div>
            <textarea id="comment" name="comment" cols="45" rows="4" required placeholder="دیدگاه شما..." ></textarea>
        </div>';

$args = array(
    'comment_field' => $yourHTML        
);

comment_form( $args );
```