# combination php and html code have error - inside hr tag in all li tag except last li tag

Tags: php, html, tags

this is my code :

```
$output .=
'<li class="recentcomments recent-comment">
    <div class="wbrc-header">
    <span class="wbrc-header-avatar">' . get_avatar( $comment, 50/*avatar_size*/ ) . '</span>
    <div class="wbrc-header-AD">
    <span class="wbrc-header-author">' . $author . '</span>
    <span class="wbrc-header-date">' . $date . '</span>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="wbrc-body">
    <span class="wbrc-body-comment">' . $comment_text . '</span>
    </div>'.

    if( ($key + 1) != $comments->count() ) {
    echo '<hr>';
    } .
'</li>';
```

in this line - i want add "hr tag" in all "li tag" - except last li - but this line have error - what i must do?

```
if( ($key + 1) != $comments->count() ) {
    echo '<hr>';
}
```

Comment: you can't have a control structure while concatanating a string! Finish the first `$output .= '...';`, then do the if and _add_ the `<hr>` to $output, after that add the `</li>`.

Comment: what is the error? plz share

Comment: I bet for a "syntax error, unexpected 'if'"

Comment: syntax error just because of concatenation with `IF`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move your condition outside the concatenation.

```
// here i am using ternary operator for your condition.
$condition = (($key + 1) != $comments->count() ? '<hr>' : '');
```

Then, you can use like that:

```
$output .=
'<li class="recentcomments recent-comment">
    <div class="wbrc-header">
    <span class="wbrc-header-avatar">' . get_avatar( $comment, 50/*avatar_size*/ ) . '</span>
    <div class="wbrc-header-AD">
    <span class="wbrc-header-author">' . $author . '</span>
    <span class="wbrc-header-date">' . $date . '</span>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="wbrc-body">
    <span class="wbrc-body-comment">' . $comment_text . '</span>
    </div>'.$condition. // change this part
'</li>';
```

Using `IF` condition with concatenation `(.)` will produce `"syntax error, unexpected 'if'"`.

Comment: ty - this method word for me - if i whant use "if-else " Instead of this single line php code - how i must do it? ( i cant set your comment to useful - wow! site dont allow me do this work

Comment: @مهدیدمرچیلو: in ternery `: ''` this part is else

Comment: what? i am never php/html worker - I'm sorry but please, if possible, make an example like before

Comment: @مهدیدمرچیلو : `$condition = (($key + 1) != $comments->count() ? '<hr>' : Add your else code here); ` after :

Comment: no - i whant myby define a function in function.php and use it in comment.php - or myby i whant define a code like this : 

if(...) {} else if(...) {} ... else {} ------- i need for solve my problem in this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54865622/php-function-add-html-to-theme-not-work

Comment: @مهدیدمرچیلو: please create a new question and share

Comment: I put my main question link in the previous comment : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54865622/php-function-add-html-to-theme-not-work